# malloc.c:3096: SYSMALLOC: Assertion failed

Tags: c, malloc

My function is as follows:

```
void Insert_ldb(int t){
    struct node_ldb *temp_ldb1,*lastnode_ldb;
    temp_ldb1=root_ldb[t];
    while(temp_ldb1->next!=NULL)
        temp_ldb1=temp_ldb1->next;
    if(temp_ldb1->next==NULL){
         lastnode_ldb=malloc(sizeof(*lastnode_ldb));//error appears at this line
         temp_ldb1->next=lastnode_ldb;
    }
}
```

and the struct node_ldb is defined as:

```
struct node_ldb{
    int sno;
    int *lvar;
    int *object;
    struct node_ldb *next;
};
```

On compiling no error appears, but on executing it terminates with the message:

> malloc.c:3096: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)` failed.
>   Aborted

The weird part is that the same function executes successfully many times prior to termination. So is it possible that the error happened somewhere else? Because even valgrind does not show any error for the same. What could be the problem?

Comment: `temp_ldb1=root_ldb[t];` Is there any guarantee that this pointer will never be NULL (or invalid) ?

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for the correction. I thought `*lastnode_ldb` causes the dereferencing which is not the case.

Comment: No, sizeof is _mostly_ a compile-time operator. It gets different for VLAs. BTW (to the OP) is there a VLA involved? Please add the definition for the struct to the question.

Comment: Did the test runs under Valgrind led to the assertion as shown in your question.

Comment: Side comment: spaces don't cost anything and they make code easier to read.

Comment: Ok. No VLA involved. Just a spurious overwrite somewhere else in your program (or the `temp_ldb1=root_ldb[t]` thing)

Comment: @wildplasser root_ldb[t] is initialized at the start. So it will not be NULL.

Comment: Looks like the malloc arena got modified/trashed by some undefined behavior happening before your Insert_ldb() is called.

Comment: And `t` is guaranteed to be within bounds (and not negative) ?

Comment: @wildplasser Its within bound. I tried running the code and checked the value of t just before the malloc.

Comment: What does *`root_ldb[t]` is initialized at the start* mean? I take it `root_ldb` is a global variable, or static in the module? How is it defined? Also (another side comment), the check `if (temp_ldb1->next == NULL)` following a `while (temp_ldb1->next != NULL)` is probably superfluous.

Comment: @mbratch : it indeed is highly suspicious. (I would use a pointer to pointer-construct in this case. And a for() loop instead of the ugly while)

Comment: it is initialised using the function void     Initialize_LDB(int t){
        root_ldb[t]=malloc(sizeof(struct node_ldb));
    root_ldb[t]->sno=0;
    root_ldb[t]->object=0;
    root_ldb[t]->lvar=0;
    root_ldb[t]->next=NULL;
}

Comment: Do you initialise the newly allocced struct in/after this function, too? (you should **at least** set the ->next member to NULL) BTW: the test `if(temp_ldb1->next==NULL){` is not necessary. After the loop it will **always** be NULL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of old and highly rated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987207/why-do-i-get-a-c-malloc-assertion-failure
However, the answer is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This intensly smells like a memory management corruption happened prior to this call to `malloc()`.

The corrupted memory management data then made this call to `malloc()` fail.

I strongly recommend to run the program using a memory checker like for example Valgrind until the malfunction had been reproduced.

Comment: The problem was actually with the way i was allocating memory earlier. I was actually assigning the memory of size size(struct) to a pointer(to the struct), whereas i should have assigned size(struct *). Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Memory is getting corrupted.  You may want to try out few simple things.

1) Put a counter in Insert_ldb.  Hopefully the program fails at the same counter value. If it does, it may make it easier to debug.

2) Add few bytes of padding to malloc, e.g. starting with 8 bytes.

3) It's generally a good idea to initialize the contents after
   getting memory with malloc.

```
#define PAD_BYTES       8

void Insert_ldv(int t)
{
    static int counter;
    struct node_ldb *temp_ldb1, *lastnode_ldb;

    counter++;
    printf("counter = %d\n", counter);

    temp_ldb1 = root_ldb[t];   
    while (temp_ldb1->next != NULL) {
        temp_ldb1 = temp_ldb1->next;
    }                               

    if (temp_ldb1->next == NULL){
        lastnode_ldb = malloc(sizeof(*lastnode_ldb) + PAD_BYTES);
        memset(lastnode_ldb, 0, sizeof(*lastnode_ldb));
        temp_ldb1->next = lastnode_ldb;
   }                                 
}
```

When the program doesn't fail with padding, then you have a workaround for the short term.  Increase PAD_BYTES by multiples of 4 until it doesn't fail.  When working fine, PAD_BYTES is the number of bytes that the memory is overflowing.

How do lvar and object get set?  I am guessing that object has probably more data items than memory allocated for it and as a consequence it is overwriting and corrupting the heap.

Also, when does the memory get freed?

Answer (score 1):

This most likely indicates heap corruption.

There are some weird things about that function. For example, the `next` filed of the new node is left uninitialized. Why? (Not even mentioning the rest of the fields.)

Also the `temp_ldb1->next==NULL` check in the `if` looks excessive, since the preceding `while` cycle ensures already that it is null at that point.

P.S. The authors of that `sYSMALLOc` used a rather bad programming practice of writing ultra-complex assertion conditions. Now we can't figure out which specific sub-condition failed.