# How to define an ofstream variable in an header file c++

Tags: c++, text, header, ofstream

I have more than one sources files and header files. They are;

`main.cpp tools.cpp hh.cpp fitness.cpp`

`tools.h hh.h fitness.h`

I want to define an `ofstream` in the `tools.h`
The `tools.h` is included in the all other sources files. But when I add the `std::ofstream myOutput;` into the `tools.h`, it says "multiple definition of myOutput". However, there is not any other line about the `myOutput` variable.
If I can define it properly, then I want to do `myOutput.open("observe.txt",std::ofstream::app);`.

Comment: A relevant snippet of code would be most helpful.

Comment: @ShauryaChats here is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377741/sigabrt-in-arrays-c-how-to-turn-to-vector/28377923?noredirect=1#comment45105668_28377923

Comment: Have `extern std::ofstream myOutput;` in tools.h, and `std::ofstream MyOutput;` in tools.cpp.  Make sure they're enclosed by the same `namespace xyz { }` blocks (if applicable), or add the namespace as a prefix in the .cpp ala `std::ofstream myNamespace::MyOutput;` That said, it's effectively a global variable which is a bit of a code smell - if possible create it as a local stack-hosted variable in the function that needs it, though that may be impractical for something like an app-wide log file.

Comment: @TonyD thank you. It worked. I need it just to collect some data. Then I will remove it. So it is not important if it is global or local. thanks again.

Comment: @TonyD I think something is wrong. I did what you said, but I have to use this variable in the other sources files. So please tell me a way to declare the `myData.txt` in globally and use it in all the sources files. I mean, for example, I'd like to type `myOuput<<"hello world"<<endl;` in the `main.cpp` too.

Comment: @Whcrs: that should already be possible as long as main.cpp has `#include "tools.h"`, so it sees the "`extern..`" statement and knows about `myOutput`.  If you are still having trouble, please tell us the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: @TonyD you didn't understand. I tell you Where to I need to declare `myOutput.open("observe.txt",std::ofstream::app);` globally. Then I wanna call `myOutput<<"hello"<<endl;`in all the other sources files. I already have `extern` in the other sources files like in the `tools.h`. But I couldn't figure out where to declare the my text file.

Comment: You're right - I didn't understand that was what you meant.  Ok - you need to do that before you use the stream: near the start of `main()` is an obvious place to do it; if there's some function in `tools.cpp` that you call before attempting output, that might be a reasonable option too; another option is to change the definition in tools.cpp to `std::ofstream myOutput("observe.txt");`, then the constructor - which is guaranteed to be called before `main()` starts running, will open the stream itself (then you'll need to make the variable an `ofstream` in tools.h too).

Comment: @TonyD -- condense those comments into an answer, and I'll upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

Put
    `extern std::ofstream myOutput;`
in tools.h, and 
    `std::ofstream MyOutput;`
in tools.cpp.
Also, put 
    `#include <fstream>`
in tools.cpp.
To not use std:: enter the line
    `using namespace std;`
in both files.
The code to open the file is in main.cpp.