# malloc calls realloc, then crashes

Tags: c, crash, malloc, embedded-linux

I am working with a daemon in a linux embedded device, the daemon crash randomly while running, usually after starting some hours. I investigated the crash report(stack dump) and detected that it crashes by 2 scenarios, follow these call traces:

- Case 1. my function -> calloc -> malloc -> realloc(crash by SIGSEGV)
- Case 2. my function -> calloc -> malloc -> realloc -> abort ->
  raise(crash by SIGABRT)

I read this link and my issue seems because of heap corruption [Why do I get a C malloc assertion failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987207/why-do-i-get-a-c-malloc-assertion-failure).

I made my own wraper version for memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc and free) to attach fences around the alloced memory and monitor them by a hash table, so I can detect buffer overflow or free twice. However it still crashes without any memory violation at my fences.

So I want to ask 2 questions:

1. Do you have any idea to debug this kind of issue?
2. When does malloc call realloc? I looked at malloc source code at glibc briefly and see no call to realloc.

Comment: If you're able to run the code on hosted Linux machine, run it under valgrind.  It will tell you where you're mismanaging memory.

Comment: Can you recreate this with a small test case ? and is the code running user space ?

Comment: I tried valgrind, but the daemon runs too slow and it leads to other problems to my device's operation

Comment: This daemon is a network appilcation at user space, it's pretty complicated with no unit test

Comment: Does the code always check the result of `calloc`, `malloc` and `realloc` for allocation failure?

Comment: If `malloc` is calling `realloc`, it is probably implementing `malloc(size)` as `realloc(NULL, size)`.

Comment: You detect buffer overflow or free twice - but do you detect *free not mallocated*?

Comment: @IanAbbott My malloc wraper function always check for original malloc return value

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, yes, free wrapper function always check whether input pointer is allocated by looking up in a hash table

Comment: Is it possible that the underlying `malloc` is actually buggy, perhaps in some special circumstance such as memory being exhausted or the available space being too fragmented to service a request?

Comment: I am sure this would be double free or access to unallocated memory. I remember I had similar issues and that was access to unallocated memory or double free. I was sure I am not accessing unallocated memory, but when I studied code deeper I was wrong. Make sure you're not accessing unallocated memory. How many bytes are you allocating? Are these sizes large? Are you sure you're not using old pointer passed to realloc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My colleague found the root cause(by investigating core dump file and libc malloc's source code), there is a point that it **writes to a freed memory** because of a bug in a linked list's delete function => corrupted memory => calloc crash.

Acually *malloc* does not call *realloc*, *malloc* calls *__malloc_consolidate* instead. In libc's obj dump file, *__malloc_consolidate'*'s asm code is under *realloc*'s asm code so I though *malloc* calls *realloc*.