# How to correct dynamic allocation of 2D Array using a typedef structure?

Tags: c, struct, memory-management

The code I've been working on is supposed to create a cache and create a 2D array from the cache using the number of its sets and the associativity of the sets. The typedef structure it is pulling from is called Block and contains an int and a long long, though this isn't used in the dynamic allocation.

```
Block** cache = (Block**)malloc(sets * sizeof(Block*));
// 2D array functions as [set#][Blocks#]
for (i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    cache[i] = (Block*)malloc(assoc * sizeof(Block*));
    for (j = 0; j < assoc; j++) {
        cache[i][j].flags = 0;
        cache[i][j].tag = 0;
    }
}
////
// Later Freed Here
for (i = 0; i < sets; i++) {
    free(cache[i]);
}
free(cache);
```

The error I receive states "Malloc Assertion Failure in sysmalloc". I have tried corrections  but none have worked, any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `cache[i] = (Block*)malloc(assoc * sizeof(Block*));` be `cache[i] = (Block*)malloc(assoc * sizeof(Block));`

Comment: ALWAYS check values returned from system calls... This code doesn't. The `sizeof()` values are the same even though they should be different. No idea of the value (or type) of `sets` or `assoc`. Using `calloc()` would eliminate some lines of code. What else??? Oh, yeah... Don't cast the return value from `m/calloc()`...

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(Block*) < sizeof(Block)` is likely true. You are probably under-allocating memory, and in doing so are likely [overwriting adjacent `malloc`-related metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2987207/2505965) when assigning to the structure members.

```
cache[i] = (Block*)malloc(assoc * sizeof(Block*));
```

should be

```
cache[i] = (Block*)malloc(assoc * sizeof(Block));
```